# How to write update query with join

Tags: sql, join

I need to update a table called `cp` whose primary key values exists in another table `uo`. For example, my `cp` table is like below, where the (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) combination is primary key:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 |  col4 
1    |  abc |   2  |  null 
2    |  xyz |   3  |  null 
3    |  mno |   4  |  null
```

And my `uo` table is like this:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 
1    |  abc |   2 
4    |  def |   3 
3    |  mno |   4
```

Now I have to update the column `col4` to '1' in rows 1 and 3 in the `cp` table because it contains exact match (`col1 = col1`, `col2 = col2`, `col3 = col3`) in the table `uo`, in a *single* update query.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: update col4 in cp with which field in uo? If you want to update col4 in cp with col1 in uo where cp.col1 = uo.col1 and cp.col2 = uo.col2 and cp.col3 = uo.col3 , Why you not just update col4 = col1 because it's must be same with uo.

Comment: Sorry, I am missunderstanding, @HariPrasad answer should do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query:

```
update `cp` join `ou` on  cp.col1=ou.col1 and cp.col2=ou.col2 and cp.col3=ou.col3 set col4=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cp.*
from cp join uo on cp.col1 = uo.col1 and cp.col2 = uo.col2 and cp.col3 = uo.col3

update cp
set cp.col4 = 1
from cp join uo on cp.col1 = uo.col1 and cp.col2 = uo.col2 and cp.col3 = uo.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the DB in question, you may or may not be able to do a join, however, a subquery should work.

```
update cp set col4=1
where exists
(
  Select * from ou where ou.col1=cp.col1 and ou.col2=cp.col2 and ou.col3=cp.col3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
UPDATE  T1
SET     T1.COLUMN4 = 'VALUE' -- SET YOUR VALUE
FROM    cp T1
INNER JOIN uo T2
        ON T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN1
           AND T1.COLUMN2 = T2.COLUMN2
           AND T1.COLUMN3 = T2.COLUMN3
```